# the meaning of "Come as many companies"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

I found the following sentence. But I couldn't understand the meaning of "come as many airlines".

> JetBlue’s budget cuts come as many airlines continue to struggle
> financially due to a significant decline in demand for air travel.

I feel it sounds like "same as other airlines". However, no sites mentions about it. Please help me to understand this sentence.

Comment: The cuts to JetBlue's budget come while many airlnes continue to struggle.

Comment: ***As:*** during the time that:
*I saw him as I was coming into the building.
He gets more attractive as he gets older.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/as

Comment: Thank you!!!! I got it!! This "come as" is NOT an idiom!!

Answer (score 1):

> JetBlue’s budget cuts(S) come(V) as(Conjunction) many airlines(S) continue(V) to struggle financially due to a significant decline in demand for air travel.

Its structure is "S1+V1 as S2+V2". S1+V1 is a main clause and 'as S2+V2' is a subordinate clause—an adverbial clause.

'as' has many meanings but the 'as' in your example means 'while' or 'during the time that' as Peter and user66974 said.

It is used to mean two actions occur at the same time like: She kissed about me as she hugged me.